# Suggestion On Integrating Google Guice In Objectify Service Classes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice, objectify

i was considering integrating Google Guice In my new project which uses objectify for datastore operations

Consider the following base class for objectify service

```
public abstract class OfyService<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public OfyService(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    ... service methods 
}
```

and , following is user entity service class

```
public final class UserService extends OfyService<User> {

    static {
        factory().register(User.class);
    }

    private UserService() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    public static UserService getInstance() {
        return UserServiceSingleton._userService;
    }

    private static class UserServiceSingleton {
        public static final UserService _userService = new UserService();
    }
}
```

All of my entity service class will follow this pattern. So i was checking to see whether Google Guice can make it better or whether current implementation is good ?

if Guice module can handle dependencies well in my case, can anyone explain me how exactly that applies in my implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly related to Objectify did you take a look at the [Objectify Best practices](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices).  As it seems they might present more straightforward approach.

Instead of using the ObjectifyService static ofy() method, use your own.

```
public class OfyService {
   static {
      factory().register(Thing.class);
      factory().register(OtherThing.class);
      ...etc
   }

   public static Objectify ofy() {
      return ObjectifyService.ofy();
   }

   public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
      return ObjectifyService.factory();
   }
}
```

Now in your code, import your own static ofy():

```
import static com.yourcode.OfyService.ofy;
Thing th = ofy().load().type(Thing).id(123L).now();
```

In this way entity registrations are made once only and always before you require them.

With regards to startup performance it depends on the instance class and complexity of entities used.  Generally even on the lowest instance class up to around 20 entity types will be possible in under a second.  Most likely only if you have hundreds of entity types another approach might make sense investigating.

With regards to Guice.  It's not obvious how it relates to the provided code, but I would suggest a couple of things:

- Generally you'll cause yourself a DI headache if you inject your Entity classes, so most likely you'll want to avoid doing that or using a factory from the entity if you really must get injected classes.
- As for data controllers, or a UserService (not in your current form) etc.  They would generally make reasonable candidates to inject dependencies into or use as injected dependencies.

Comment: ya i have followed the objectify best pratices and implemented with my needs, except the entities registration part , which i encapsulated with abstract class, but still, there is chance of entity not registered while quering in some other part, will address that. thanks!